# Trying to adapt an old program to draw a grid of squares

Tags: java, android, grid

I have a previous program that I made that draws a grid of rectangles with a set separation value, I am trying to now change this code to allow me to draw a grid of squares in the exact same way, I figured this would be an easy change but it has been anything but that so far! I have included what I have tried below, I tried to change all of the parameters and calculations but no matter what I do it only ever seems to include one rectangle rather than filling the board as it does when I use circles. Does anybody have any ideas why this is happening?

```
    public class GameView extends View {

    private Game mGame = new Game(Game.DEFAULT_COLUMNS,
            Game.DEFAULT_ROWS);

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    private Paint mBGPaint;
    private Paint mPlayer2Paint;
    private Paint mGridPaint;
    private Paint mPlayer1Paint;

    double SEPATRATOR_RATIO;
    int rowcount;
    int columncount;

    private float diameterX;
    private float diameterY;
    private float diameter;

    private float separator;
    public float availableWidth;
    public float availableHeight;
    private int tokenAtPos;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();

    //        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new 
    MyGestureListener());
    }

    private void init() {
        mGridPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mGridPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mGridPaint.setColor(0xff0000ff);
        mPlayer1Paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPlayer1Paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPlayer1Paint.setColor(0xffff0000);
        mPlayer2Paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPlayer2Paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPlayer2Paint.setColor(0xffffff00);
        mBGPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBGPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mBGPaint.setColor(0xffffffff);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        double SEPARATOR_RATIO=5;
        int rowcount = mGame.getmRows();
        int columncount = mGame.getmColumns();

        double diameterX = floor(getWidth()/(columncount+(columncount+1)*SEPARATOR_RATIO));
        double diameterY = ceil(getHeight()/(columncount+(columncount+1)*SEPARATOR_RATIO));

        double diameter = (Math.min(diameterX, diameterY));

        float separator = (float) (diameter * SEPARATOR_RATIO);

        double availableWidth = (columncount+1) * diameter * SEPARATOR_RATIO
                + columncount * diameterX;

        double availableHeight = (columncount+1) * diameter * SEPARATOR_RATIO
                + columncount * diameterX;

        canvas.drawRect(0,0,(float)availableWidth, (float)availableHeight,mGridPaint);

        for (int col=0;col<mGame.getmColumns(); col++)
        {
            for(int row=0; row<mGame.getmRows(); row++)
            {
                Paint paint;
//                tokenAtPos = mGame.getToken(col,row);
//                if (tokenAtPos==1)
//                { paint=mPlayer1Paint; }
//                else if (tokenAtPos==2)
//                { paint=mPlayer2Paint; }
//                else
                { paint=mBGPaint; }
                float cx = (float)(separator+(diameter+separator)*col+diameter/2);
                float cy = (float) (separator+(diameter+separator)*row+diameter/2);
//                canvas.drawCircle (cx, cy, (float)diameter/2, paint);
                canvas.drawRect (cx, cy, (float)diameterX, (float)diameterY, paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You changed from rectangles to squares. And you talked aboud circles. I cannot follow you.

Comment: As far as I am aware, to draw a square you have to draw a rectangle with the dimensions of a square? I am trying to change the circles to squares.

Comment: Circles? Where are the circles? You said `have a previous program that I made that draws a grid of rectangles `.

Comment: I've commented out the previous part that drew circles - canvas.drawCircle (cx, cy, (float)diameter/2, paint);

Comment: ???? `have a previous program that I made that draws a grid of rectangles with a set separation value, I am trying to now change this code to allow me to draw a grid of squares `

Comment: It looks af if you do not reralize that you brought confusion. When are you going to rectify?